# Control phone on MacBook Pro via bluetooth?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, bluetooth, macos, 4.2-jelly-bean, ad-hoc-networks

I'd like to control my Galaxy Nexus via my Macbook Pro via VPN ([Virtual Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)).

Since connecting the Galaxy Nexus to an Adhoc, WiFi created by the MacBook Pro doesn't work. That's why I'd like to do it via bluetooth.

Is that possible and if yes, how?

Comment: What type of control are you trying to achieve? Make phone calls? Access Internet? Access phone data like pictures?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was posted entitled "Software to control mobile phone via bluetooth" over at Superuser.com on 11th December 2012 to which I responded:

https://superuser.com/questions/517884/software-to-control-mobile-phone-via-bluetooth/517888#517888

My response was this:

A program called Remote Professional from mobileways.de claims to be able to make calls from your PC-mobile. There is a brief article about it entitled Remotely Control Your Phone from Computer from Technize.com

A youtube video and link to download the program is also included: http://www.technize.com/remotely-control-your-phone-from-computer/

However this method used a PC rather than an Apple Mac. It may well be possible that mobileways.de offer a similar program for Macs.

So in theory what you have asked is perfectly plausible, if they haven't developed a program for apple macs, they may do in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

i have been able to do it partially 
"1keyboard" it lets you use your macbook to type in your android phone. which is great since one of my androids has a twitchy screen. o i use it to type, i also saw one for a mouse, but i lost the link.

Comment: Exposing how you are able to do it even partially with steps and linking the source would help OP. Please edit your answer to include this